# Wordpress Get title variable not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, title

i'm trying to use

```
<?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?>
```

to read the title of wordpress post but for some reason is not working on my wordpress blog :(
Here is the post:

```
http://tinyurl.com/mxq25wb
```

And here is what i'm using as source code for image button

```
<a href="http://www.downloadthesefiles.com/Download/?ci=8138&amp;q=&lt;?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?&gt;" rel="nofollow"><img class="alignnone wp-image-1133 size-full" src="http://hack-games.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/download-no-survey.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="59" /></a>
```

and this as download link:

```
<a href="http://www.downloadthesefiles.com/Download/?ci=8138&amp;q=&lt;?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?&gt;" rel="nofollow">Download Mirror2</a>
```

If i use this is not even showing the download link:

```
<a href="http://www.downloadthesefiles.com/Download/?ci=8138&amp;q=<?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?>" rel="nofollow">Download Now Mirror2</a>
```

Do i have to add anything else to make it working ?

Also noticed the javascript is not working on my wordpress and i don't know how to fix it, i can't add even a simple alert to my wordpress site :(
maybe a code in header?

Please help me, thank you !

Comment: Tried to add the code from here: http://wpbandit.com/blog/easily-add-javascript-to-your-wordpress-themes/ in my theme functions.php but it is still not working ...

Comment: Someone please tell me what is the problem, what do i have to do ? i`ve search a lot of hours but didn`t found a solution ... i know only some html, i don`t know php and i don`t have experience with wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Because your php tag is &lt;?php" and of course, it doesn't work.

Also, You should convert your string into web safe uri.

Try this.

```
<a href="http://www.downloadthesefiles.com/Download/?ci=8138&q=
<?php echo urlencode(get_the_title($post->ID)); ?>" rel="nofollow">Download Mirror2</a>
```

And this is why your this guide link doesn't work.

Change this:

```
<em>If you have any download problems read <a href=" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-article','http://www.downloadthesefiles.com']);"http://hack-games.info/download/">this guide</a> !</em>
```

to this:

```
<em>If you have any download problems read <a href="http://hack-games.info/download/" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-article','http://www.downloadthesefiles.com']);">this guide</a> !</em>
```

**EDIT**
Your php codes doesn't work because **you can't use php in articles**.

Comment: I used it now as you can see and know is not even showing the download link ... and you can see that there is an error ... can you check please ? thanks a lot !

Comment: just like there is no </a> to the end ... i`m not sure why ... just hover your mouse over "this guide" below download button and you will see the error ...

Comment: i've also tried with <?php wp_title( '' ); ?> and i get this link as download link: http://www.downloadthesefiles.com/Download/?ci=8138&q=%3C?php%20wp_title(

Comment: your theme codes are so bad. And looks like some php codes doesn't work, i don't know why.

Comment: i updated the answer. You can't use php in articles. I recommend you to write url manually.

Comment: can you please login using user: titlehelp and password Abcd1234 and test it ? thanks a lot !

Comment: A new wordpress blog, or any wordpress blog. It doesn't change anything. I suppose to you talking about your theme codes and I tried to help you. In articles, you **can't use any php codes**.

Comment: no matter dude. Forget my codes, you can't execute any php codes in your article.